# insert on duplicate update, always insert

Tags: mysql

I have the next query:

```
Insert into tableA (userID, switch, plateType, groupVal, brokeage) 
Select 'UserB', switch, plateType, groupVal, brokeage from tableA  where userID = 'UserA' 
      on duplicate key Update brokeage = (Select brokeage from tableA  where userID = 'UserA')
```

The primary key of tableA is a field named id, which is unique and auto increment.
The problem with this query is that it always inserts, instead of updating, when the row already exists. I don't use the id in the query, I don`t know if this is the problem...if any one has an answer for me, thanks.

Comment: Of the columns you are inserting, which do you expect to be unique? You said `TableA.id` is the PK, auto-increment, but you're not directly inserting that.  Do you intend for `userID` to be unique too?  What column determines whether the row already exists?

Comment: Just TableA.id is unique, and i don`t directly insert it because it would auto-increment automatically, but if this approach is wrong please feel free to correct me

Comment: So when you insert then, which value(s) do you expect to trigger the `ON DUPLICATE KEY`?  What constitutes a unique row?

Comment: yes i know i don`t specify which value trigger the ON DUPLICATE KEY, and that is where i am confused, and the values that make a row unique are the combination of userID, plateType, groupVal. but just the combination, i mean, userdID will repeat as many times as it can be combine with plateType and groupVal...i hope i made myself clear. And thank you for your time by the way

Comment: Yes, now it is understandable. You'll need a unique index for those columns-- hang on and I'll put a full answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` action to take place, MySQL needs to know that it has attempted to insert a duplicate of what columns *you* consider to be unique. That doesn't just involve the `PRIMARY KEY`, but any combination of columns you consider unique.  Since you are concerned that the combination of `userID, plateType, groupVal` together be unique, create a compound index for those three columns.  Then your `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UDPATE` should work as you expect it to.

This will add the correct unique index to your existing table. When the combination of columns is found on `INSERT`, MySQL will take the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` action instead.

```
ALTER TABLE `tableA` ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx_user_plate_group` (`userID`, `plateType`, `groupVal`);
```

Comment: one last question about this, this means the previous primary key i had, must be deleted, i mean the one i called id and that is auto-increment.

Comment: @emc No, you do not need to delete it.  You may not _need_ it, but you don't need to delete it either. If it is used as a foreign key in other tables, you'll need it and it is harmless to keep it in place otherwise.  When MySQL does `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, it checks for duplication of _any_ index that needs to be unique, not just the PK. You can have multiple defined unique indexes.

Comment: @emc If you didn't intend to use the auto-increment id as a foreign key elsewhere, you could have defined those three columns as a compound primary key in the first place, but this new unique index will do just as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Michael Berkowski and for taking time to help a total strange...I appreciate it, and hope i could help you some day. Take care.

Comment: Another problem came up, I am going to make another question, so it will give you more points in case you want to answer...well i guess will give you more points, I`m new in this so don`t really know how the scoring stuff works ..well the subject will be: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row, in case interests you.